# Why does "for(std::size_t i=2; i >= 0; --i)" fail

Tags: c++

I was surprised when this `for` loop failed to run properly:

```
for (std::size_t i=2; i >= 0; --i)
```

I figured, okay, probably the final check is if `-1 >= 0`, and since `i` is not allowed to be negative, we have a problem. Presumably `i` is looping around to (2<sup>64</sup> - 1).

However, this `for` loop does execute:

```
for (std::size_t i=2; i+1 > 0; --i)
```

Ignoring `std::size_t` for a moment; this doesn't make sense to me from a logical perspective. Both `(i+1 > 0)` and `(i >= 0)` will be either true or false for the exact same values of `i`.

Both will be true if `i = {0, 1, 2, ...}` and false if `i = {-1, -2, -3, ...}`.

What is going on here?

Is it something to do with the implementation of `std::size_t`, or the compiler, or am I just missing something very obvious?

Comment: You just have to apply the same reasoning to the second example that you applied to the second one. `-1 + 1` is `0` whether it is in `signed` or `unsigned` integer arithmetic.

Comment: *and false if i = {-1, -2, -3, ...}* ... except that `i` (which is **unsigned**) cannot be any of those values, because those values are all negative.

Comment: This question may need more clarity.  You mention "i is not allowed to be negative", and then describe "if i = {-1, -2, -3, ...}".  Are those statements not contradictory?  What does "failed to run properly" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is going on here?

`std::size_t` is an unsigned integer type.

> ```
> i >= 0
> ```

All unsigned integers are greater than or equal to 0. There exists no value for which this relation would be false and hence the loop cannot end.

> ```
> i+1 > 0
> ```

An unsigned integer **can** be 0. Hence this relation can be false and the loop can end. Example:

```
std::size_t i = 0;
i -= 1;
assert(i+1 == 0);
```

The value of `i` that ends the loop is congruent with -1 modulo M, where M is the number of representable values which is 2<sup>b</sup> where b is the width of the integer type in bits. That number is the greatest representable value i.e. 2<sup>b</sup>-1.

Your deduction works with whole numbers, but it doesn't work with modular arithmetic.

---

This is to some degree a matter of taste, but I recommend following code to loop over numbers (n..0]. It works correctly with both signed and unsigned types:

```
for (std::size_t i=n; i-- > 0;)
```

Comment: Ah yes, the elusive C _arrow_ operator `i --> 0`!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This time it's in disguise ;)

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is an unsigned type. In such types, negative values don't exist, but 0-1 is defined to be the value to which adding 1 would give 0 – the maximum representable integer value of `size_t`.

So, yes:

> I figured, okay, probably the final check is if -1 >= 0, and since i is not allowed to be negative, we got a problem. Presumably i is looping around to 2^64 - 1.

exactly.

> ```
> for (std::size_t i=2; i+1 > 0; --i)
> ```

So, `i` reaches 2⁶⁴-1, and you add 1, so you get `0`, which is *not* `>0`, and your loop exits.

Everything's fine here!